# Target using grunt-contrib-coffee

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-coffee

I'm using [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) in an AngularJS project and I'm trying to set configuration options based on grunt's target. I have the following configuration file (using [grunt-load-options](https://github.com/chriszarate/grunt-load-options)):

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  return {
    stage: {
      glob_to_multiple: {
          expand: true,
          nonull: true,
          cwd: 'src/js/',
          src: ['*.coffee', 'config/stage.coffee'],
          dest: '.tmp/js/',
          ext: '.js'
      }
    }
  };
};
```

But when I execute the task using `grunt coffee:stage` no files are copied. Any ideas?

```
Running "coffee:stage" (coffee) task
>> 0 files created.

Done, without errors.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure the config file is named correctly? In this case `coffee.js`?

Comment: had any luck with that?

Comment: Yes, correctly named.

Answer (score 1):

A correct configuration for `grunt-config-coffee` would need to start with `coffee`, and then, as in your case, with the specific config (use `stage` instead of `glob_to_multiple`):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  return {
    coffee: {
      stage: {
          expand: true,
          nonull: true,
          cwd: 'src/js/',
          src: ['*.coffee', 'config/stage.coffee'],
          dest: '.tmp/js/',
          ext: '.js'
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error:
    
    Running "coffee:stage" (coffee) task
    Verifying property coffee.stage exists in config...ERROR
    >> Unable to process task.
    Warning: Required config property "coffee.stage" missing. Use --force  to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.